# How to call a function based on the input value?

Tags: c++, function

Lets say I want to only call one function in my code: func(), but depending on which value I give it, have it go STRAIGHT to the correct 'version' of that function?

I know this would be possible to do with if-statements/switch-statements, but then it would have to (inefficiently) check which value was passed. I was hoping there's a pre-compiled way to do it?

Is something like this possible to do in an efficient way?

```
func(3)
```

Will execute the third version of func()

```
func[1]{
    cout "One";
}

func[2]{
    cout "Two";
}

func[3]{
    cout "Three";
}
```

Comment: If you name your functions `func1`, `func2`, and `func3`, you can use the preprocessor: `#define func(x) func ## x()`.  I'm sure there's a more C++-ey way to do it, but I'm no expert on that topic, I'm afraid.

Comment: I wish you had used an example that didn't cause everyone to misinterpret your question.

Comment: Do you take your input from an external source or is it known at compile time? This can affect the answers you get.

Comment: If you are worried about efficiency to this degree, I recommend learning assembly for whatever platform you use and seeing what kind of code the compiler generates after it optimizes. This will also give you an idea of how fast various operations are.

Answer (score 6):

You could have an array of function pointers:

```
int foo_1() {
   cout << "One";
}

// ...

auto[] functions = {foo_1, foo_2, foo_3};
```

and call it with

```
 functions[0]();
```

Comment: damn :P why didnt i think of that. Definitely more what the asker wants than templated functions.

Comment: To be honest, this solution reeks of C, and there's probably a "more C++" solution.

Comment: This may be faster if there are a significant number of options. However, when the if statements are so simple, an indirect branch will likely be slower due to issues with branch prediction/pipeline efficiency.

Comment: Thanks Tordek. By the way, I'm trying to apply your code, but in another scenario that I have.How can I declare then define a function pointer for a standard variable (not array) inside of a struct? So that later I can just do: myStruct.pointerFunc() which would redirect to func()?

Comment: I don't know how you'd do that in C++, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, case-switch is very efficient, because even if you have a very large number of targets, it can compile this in the code as a table of jumps, rather than as a chain of ifs - so all parts of the switch will be an equal amount of instructions away.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Compilation

> If the range of input values is identifiably 'small' and has only a
>   few gaps, some compilers that incorporate an optimizer may actually
>   implement the switch statement as a branch table or an array of
>   indexed function pointers instead of a lengthy series of conditional
>   instructions.* This allows the switch statement to determine instantly
>   what branch to execute without having to go through a list of
>   comparisons.

Furthermore:

1) Don't worry about premature optimization if you haven't identified the code as a bottleneck that's slowing your program down.

2) Why does calling a function with different values make it do entirely different things? Shouldn't it be different functions, instead? (If you want to call a bunch of functions in a loop, you could always create an array of function pointers - look up function pointers)

Comment: Thanks, thats very good to know that switch is efficient like that.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `func(3)`, where the argument(s) are constant, the compiler will automatically optimize the function if it has no side effects. This means the function may not modify a global variable, member variable, or write to any pointers passed to the function. The `if` statements will disappear at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it could be possible to use a templated function for this.

Eg

```
template< int subfunc>
void func< subfunc>();

void func<1>();
```

Something like this should work :)

That way when you call it you say: `func<1>();` and it will call the other function.

Just checked it. This solution will not work as the user wishes since the entered value in the chevrons must be a constant/compile-time resolved value.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're tough men using C++ here, I would use a `map` from `string` (your input) to `void *` (represents all the functions), and this way I won't need to count on any specific order of my callable functions in the map. I also don't need to convert the input to a number (in case the input is from the console and it's a string)

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>     // for cout

using namespace std;    // that's the way I like it

int main()
{
    map<string, void *> funcs;

    funcs["func1"] = (void *)func1;
    funcs["func2"] = (void *)func2;
    ...

    string s = myinput();
    if (funcs.find(s) != funcs.end()) {
        ((void (*)())funcs[s])();   // call the function (first casting it to the function's data type
    }
    else cout << "### Error: function " << s << " doesn't exist in map" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since we're uber tough men using C++ let's not use C style casts or casts that are unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with value templates.  But if you're doing that, why have a function at all?  And why not just have N differently named functions, it will be FAR less confusing when maintaining your code.